# Is there a way to get Jenkins to serve up folder contents on the server?

Tags: jenkins

After a jenkins build, I run a set of automated acceptance tests. In one of the reports from the acceptance tests, there is a link to a directory containing logs files. Jenkins won't serve up this directory unless I append ** to the URL. Is there any way to configure Jenkins to automatically resolve the URL, without **.

I can get the logs through the Build Artefacts, but you need to be logged in to see the artefacts, and I am often trying to view logs on jenkins instances where I don't have a log in for. Also, people often remove the Build Artefacts to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append `**` to the URL, jenkins will serve up the directory under the URL. So if your URL is `http://jenkins.com/myfolder`, `http://jenkins.com/myfolder/**` will serve up the contents of 'myfolder'